# Criando uma List<> a partir de um Json C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Tenho um duvida em relação a JSON, tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "result":{
    "nr":26,
    "lista":[
      {
        "codigo":"2",
        "nome":"Pratos Quentes",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"3",
        "nome":"Sobremesas",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"4",
        "nome":"Bebidas Nao Alcoolicas",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"7",
        "nome":"Cocktails",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"10",
        "nome":"Cafes",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"11",
        "nome":"Consummes",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"12",
        "nome":"Porções",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      },
      {
        "codigo":"13",
        "nome":"Chocolates",
        "foto":"./images/cupcake.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id":138827
}
```

gostaria de saber como pego o atributo lista e converto num List<> ou array de objetos em C#.

Comment: Você pretende fazer tudo "manualmente" ou usar uma biblioteca que abstraia isso?

Comment: Tô tentando com Newtonsoft.Json mas não tô conseguindo achar um examplo na documentação

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça as seguintes classes para obter o mesmo `layout` desse [json](/questions/tagged/json) com o pacote [Newtonsoft.Json - Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) decorando cada propriedade da seguinte forma:

```
public class Base
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("jsonrpc")]
    public string JsonRpc { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Result
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("nr")]
    public int Nr { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("lista")]
    public List<Items> Lista { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Items
{

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("codigo")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }
}
```

depois utilize assim:

```
string value = File.ReadAllText("arq.json");
Base b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(value);
```

pronto assim é carregado as informações do [json](/questions/tagged/json) para essa classe `Base`.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Newtonsoft.Json - Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)
- [Json.NET - Popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
- [Json.NET Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)
- [Json.NET Documentation - Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: Obrigado Virgílio por compartilhar conhecimento!

Answer (score 12):

No visual studio você consegue transformar qualquer `string` no padrão `json` em  classe C#, para tanto basta seguir os passos a baixo:

> *Edit > Past Special > Past JSON As Class*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Classe gerada pelo visual studio**

```
public class Base
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int nr { get; set; }
    public Lista[] lista { get; set; }
}

public class Lista
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string foto { get; set; }
}
```

---

Depois com a sua classe criada automaticamente pelo visual studio, você faz a conversão para o objeto utilizando a biblioteca do **NewtonSoft.Json**

```
string value = File.ReadAllText("arq.json");
Base b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(value);
```

Comment: Tiago, sensacional isto daqui. Obrigado pelo aprendizado!

Answer (score 0):

Ou, você pode utilizar um conversor de json para object c# como esse, por exemplo: https://jsonutils.com/

E também não precisaria usar pacote de terceiros com: 
new System.Web.Script.Serialization

```
 var objConvert = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(stringJson, typeof(tipodoseuobjeto))
```