# Erro Deserialize Json em Modelo C#

Tags: c#, json

Amigos, estou recebendo erro para fazer o deserialize do seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "Comanda": [
        {
            "status": "Produzido (Codigo 3)",
            "estabelecimento_id": 18,
            "cliente_nome": "Marcos Manfrin",
            "estabelecimento": "Aquaria",
            "formas_de_pagamentos": [
                {
                    "valor_final": "69.00",
                    "valor_total": "120.00",
                    "tipo": "Dinheiro"
                },
                {
                    "valor_final": "69.00",
                    "valor_total": "120.00",
                    "tipo": "Débito Visa"
                }
            ],
            "apto": "402",
            "pedido_id": 35370,
            "data_venda": "07/06/2017",
            "items": [
                {
                    "quantidade": 4,
                    "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
                    "valor_custo": "1.00",
                    "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: patricia_vitoriam@yahoo.com.br",
                    "descricao": "",
                    "produto_id": 78693,
                    "valor_venda": "20.00"
                },
                {
                    "quantidade": 2,
                    "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
                    "valor_custo": "1.00",
                    "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: solange.sol@bol.com.br",
                    "descricao": "",
                    "produto_id": 78694,
                    "valor_venda": "20.00"
                }
            ],
            "comanda": "2103",
            "fotografo_id": 36,
            "fotografo": "Jaasiel Oliveira",
            "codigo": "C819F0"
        }
    ]
}
```

No seguinte modelo:

```
public class FormasDePagamento
{
    public string valor_final { get; set; }
    public string valor_total { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string valor_custo { get; set; }
    public string observacoes { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public int produto_id { get; set; }
    public string valor_venda { get; set; }
}

public class Comanda
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int estabelecimento_id { get; set; }
    public string cliente_nome { get; set; }
    public string estabelecimento { get; set; }
    public List<FormasDePagamento> formas_de_pagamentos { get; set; }
    public string apto { get; set; }
    public int pedido_id { get; set; }
    public string data_venda { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public string comanda { get; set; }
    public int fotografo_id { get; set; }
    public string fotografo { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
}
```

Estou utilizando esse código:

```
var PedidosApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.Comanda>>(json);
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].Comanda', line 1, position 14.'
```

Alguém me dá uma luz, por favor.

Comment: Exemplos: [Criando uma List<> a partir de um Json C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199649/criando-uma-list-a-partir-de-um-json-c/199656#199656) e [Deserialize json string array to string array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227425/deserialize-json-string-array-to-string-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cria essa classe

```
public class Json
{
    public List<Models.Comanda> Comanda { get; set; }
}
```

Utiliza ela como type parameter do método DeserializeObject

```
var PedidosApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json>(json);
```

Comment: Isso responde a pergunta +1!

Answer (score 3):

Se você precisa de uma lista de comandas, faltou criar a classe root que encapsula a lista de comandas do seu Json.

```
public class Rootobject
{
        public List<Comanda> Comandas { get; set; }
}
```

A chamada fica:

```
var pedidosApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

E por fim renomeei o array de comanda do Json para comandas.

```
 "Comandas": [...
```

Você pode usar `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bar")]` para organizar questões de nomenclatura entre as classes c# e as propriedades do Json.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pois o seu Json está montado diferente da sua conversão

O que o seu json deve ter é uma lista de objetos do tipo `Comanda`.
Abaixo segue o Json correto:

```
[
    {
        "status": "Produzido (Codigo 3)",
        "estabelecimento_id": 18,
        "cliente_nome": "Marcos Manfrin",
        "estabelecimento": "Aquaria",
        "formas_de_pagamentos": [
            {
                "valor_final": "69.00",
                "valor_total": "120.00",
                "tipo": "Dinheiro"
            },
            {
                "valor_final": "69.00",
                "valor_total": "120.00",
                "tipo": "Débito Visa"
            }
        ],
        "apto": "402",
        "pedido_id": 35370,
        "data_venda": "07/06/2017",
        "items": [
            {
                "quantidade": 4,
                "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
                "valor_custo": "1.00",
                "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: patricia_vitoriam@yahoo.com.br",
                "descricao": "",
                "produto_id": 78693,
                "valor_venda": "20.00"
            },
            {
                "quantidade": 2,
                "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
                "valor_custo": "1.00",
                "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: solange.sol@bol.com.br",
                "descricao": "",
                "produto_id": 78694,
                "valor_venda": "20.00"
            }
        ],
        "comanda": "2103",
        "fotografo_id": 36,
        "fotografo": "Jaasiel Oliveira",
        "codigo": "C819F0"
    }
]
```

Com esse json você consegue deserializar para List();

Veja funcionando no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYDkeh)

Comment: Infelizmente, não posso alterar o JSON, pois ele já vem de outro sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Para converter o Json fiz os seguintes ajustes:
- Retirar a hierarquia que contem o objeto Comanda
- Retirar a chaves dentro da hierarquia de comanda, pois só existe um objeto
- Retirar o List da deserialização

Segue o Json:

```
{
    "status": "Produzido (Codigo 3)",
    "estabelecimento_id": 18,
    "cliente_nome": "Marcos Manfrin",
    "estabelecimento": "Aquaria",
    "formas_de_pagamentos": [
        {
            "valor_final": "69.00",
            "valor_total": "120.00",
            "tipo": "Dinheiro"
        },
        {
            "valor_final": "69.00",
            "valor_total": "120.00",
            "tipo": "Débito Visa"
        }
    ],
    "apto": "402",
    "pedido_id": 35370,
    "data_venda": "07/06/2017",
    "items": [
      {
            "quantidade": 4,
            "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
            "valor_custo": "1.00",
            "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: patricia_vitoriam@yahoo.com.br",
            "descricao": "",
            "produto_id": 78693,
            "valor_venda": "20.00"
        },
        {
            "quantidade": 2,
            "nome": "FOTO EM ARQUIVO DIGITAL",
            "valor_custo": "1.00",
            "observacoes": "Mandar para esse e-mail: solange.sol@bol.com.br",
            "descricao": "",
            "produto_id": 78694,
            "valor_venda": "20.00"
        }
    ],
    "comanda": "2103",
    "fotografo_id": 36,
    "fotografo": "Jaasiel Oliveira",
    "codigo": "C819F0"
}
```

Segue o comando

```
var PedidosApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Comanda>(json);
```